# wxPython - problems with messagedialog

Tags: python, wxpython

i'm a newby and am trying to learn wxpython. i got this code off a video tutorial on youtube. it's supposed to show a dialog box with an 'ok' button. it works in the demo in the video, but the dialog box just doesn't appear when i do it. 
i added the print statements to debug the code. the program seems to be going through all the steps but the dialog box just doesn't appear.

i also get this message in the terminal console: Python[3700:d07] Can't open input server /Library/InputManagers/Inquisitor

thanks in advance,

here's the code:

```
import wx

class bucky(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        print 'initialising frame'
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, id, 'frame aka window', size=(300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)


        print 'about to create box'

        box = wx.MessageDialog(None,'go on', 'title', wx.OK)
        answer=box.ShowModal()
        box.Destroy()


if __name__=='__main__':
    print 'program begins'
    app=wx.App()
    print 'app created'
    frame = bucky(parent=None, id=-1)
    print 'frame instantiated'
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: How are you executing your code? Please provide details regarding what wxPython version and OS you are using.

Comment: Hi, i'm on OSX Mavericks, Python 2.7.6, wxPython version 3.0.0.0 cocoa classic. i'm executing my code through the terminal. (by the way, the indentation of the if __name__ section appears messed up on the site but is fine in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem, still can't figure out why the dialog is cancelled when initiated, but we can initiate it *twice* to solve that.

```
    box = wx.MessageDialog(None,'go on', 'title', wx.OK)
    box.ShowModal()
    box.ShowModal()
    box.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It worked fine on windows 8 with wxPython v3.0

```
import wx

class bucky(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        print 'initialising frame'
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, id, 'frame aka window', size=(300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        print 'about to create box'
        box = wx.MessageDialog(None,'go on', 'title', wx.OK)
        box.ShowModal()
        box.Destroy()

if __name__=='__main__': 
    print 'program begins' 
    app=wx.App() 
    print 'app created' 
    frame = bucky(parent=None, id=-1) 
    print 'frame instantiated' 
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: i don't see any problems with the code.Unfortunately I am not a Mac user. so I can't test on a Mac. Maybe this is an OS specific issue.